# How to set Adapter for listview with image in Android

Tags: java, xml

I have to click a button to show ListView with image. Unfortunately, the application  stops when I click on the button. I have also set the custom adapter too but still the same. Here is the code:

```
public class R1 extends Activity {
        String[] signTitle;
        String[] signDescription;
        int images[]={R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.     f,R.drawable.g,R.drawable.h};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.r1);
        Resources res = getResources();
        signTitle = res.getStringArray(R.array.titile);
        signDescription = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        Customlistadapter adapter = new Customlistadapter(this,signTitle,images,signDescription);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

customAdpater.java

```
public class Customlistadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;
    public Customlistadapter(Context c, String[] title, int imgs[],String[] desc) {
        super(c, R.layout.activity_show,R.id.textView1,title);
        this.context = c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.titleArray = title;
        this.descriptionArray = desc;
 }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show, parent,false);
         ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
         TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
         myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
         myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
         return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack trace of error would be great to see. Ass well as the values of 'title', 'imgs' and 'desc' variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could post the LogCat or at least point out the line which produces the error, we could help you better.
Also Initializing a ListView like this is highly inefficient.

Implementing a Viewholder Patter helps.

Optimized CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
 {
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] titleArray;
    String[] descriptionArray;
    public CustomListAdapter(Context c, String[] title, int imgs[],String[] desc) {
        super(c, R.layout.activity_show,R.id.textView1,title);
        this.context = c;
        this.images = imgs;
        this.titleArray = title;
        this.descriptionArray = desc;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if(convertView == null)
        {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show, parent,false);

            viewHolder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            viewHolder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            if(titleArray[position] != null)
            {
                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                viewHolder.title= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                viewHolder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                viewHolder.image.setImageResource(images[position]);
                viewHolder.title.setText(titleArray[position]);
                viewHolder.description.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView title,description;
        ImageView image;
    }
```

}

Comment: this is log cat error `04-26 08:51:37.012: E/OpenGLRenderer(1036): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-26 08:51:37.104: E/OpenGLRenderer(1036): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
`04-26 08:51:51.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 08:51:51.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1036): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
04-26 08:51:51.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-26 08:51:51.628: E/AndroidRuntime(1036):  ... 44 more

Comment: It says the error is in your layouts .xml file, the sixth line. It can't get the value MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.